# copy of select not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Items>
  <Item>
   <Name>Ram-345D</Name>
   <Price>$21.00</Price>
   <Warranty>2 Years </Warranty>
  </Item>
 </Items>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/Item"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to select all the nodes and the elements of `Item` and display them. But my copy of select is not working. what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong. This should be

```
    <xsl:copy-of select="/Item"/>
```

this;

```
    <xsl:copy-of select="//Item"/>
```

then you will get the Items and its children with the elements,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
   <Name>Ram-345D</Name>
   <Price>$21.00</Price>
   <Warranty>2 Years </Warranty>
</Item>
```

Comment: Note that this solution will copy all `Item`s from *everywhere* in the input document over to the output document; also, the resulting output document will not be well formed because it will have multiple root elements.  OP might want to output a common, enclosing root element and may want to consider using an [identity template pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20257070/290085) instead.

Answer (score 1):

**You could adjust your XSLT as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/Items">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Item"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**to copy the `Item` elements as you requested:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
    <Name>Ram-345D</Name>
    <Price>$21.00</Price>
    <Warranty>2 Years </Warranty>
  </Item>
```

**But note if you have multiple `Item` elements, your output will not be well-formed XML document because it will lack a single root element.**

Instead, consider starting with the identity transformation, and overriding it for those elements with which you'd like to do something different than copy exactly.

For example, this XSLT will copy everything over to the output except for the `Price` of `Item`s named "Ram-345D", which it will change to "Free":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Item[Name = 'Ram-345D']/Price">
    <Price>Free</Price>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```